# Resize ImageViews to fit and use full screen width in Android

Tags: android, xml, imageview, resize-image

How can I fit these two (or more) marbles (ImageViews) to the full width of the Android screen?

The full screen should be used all the time, regardless of if there are 1 or 12 marbles.
Right now only 1½ marble fits, so some resize are needed!

In conclusion I would like to be able to add as many ImageViews as needed and they should automagically be resized to fit within but also use the whole Android display width...

[image]

My XML-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/background_360x780_fireboxes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMarble1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_marble_dark_yellow_246x246" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMarble2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgMarble1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_marble_dark_yellow_246x246" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnQuit"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
        android:onClick="quit"
        android:text="@string/btn_quit"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:text="@string/btn_play"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Make every marble ImageView with width=0dp.
Make imgMarble1 startToStart of parent and endToStartOf imgMarble2.
Make imgMarble2 start to end of imgMarble1 and endtoend of parent.

This will create a chain and width will be autoresize based on screen width.

Comment: Amazing, that actually worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Thanks @FilipeOliveira for your help:

From his comments above...***

This is how you fit two (or more) marbles (ImageViews) within the Android display width:

- Set `width = 0dp` for every marble (ImageView)
  `android:layout_width="0dp"`
- Set imgMarble1's "Start" to "StartOf parent" and "End" to "StartOf imgMarble2"
  `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`
  `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgMarble2"`
- Set imgMarble2's "Start" to "EndOf imgMarble1" and "End" to "EndOf Parent"
  `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgMarble1"`
  `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

"This will create a chain and the width will be auto resize based on screen width."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMarble1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgMarble2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/marble_dark_yellow_246x246" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMarble2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgMarble1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/marble_dark_yellow_246x246" />
```

[image: Two ImageViews resized to fit and use the full screen width in Android]